# how to support margin-top and margin bottom in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKeditor and I want to set margin-top and margin-bottom for many paragraphs in my text but it does not work. These what I have tried till now:

1- use margin top directly inside the editor

```
<h2 style="margin-top:40px">What are tokens?</h2>
```

2- I added a new style to contents.css:

```
p.ex1 
{
    margin-top: 100cm;
}
```

then in the editor I wrote:

```
<p class="ex1">What are tokens?</p>
```

Both ways did not work for, I am using a full toolbar of CKeditor v4.6.2

Any other way to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell CKEditor to load your CSS rules and to allow your `class` attributes in `<p>` tags:

Create a new file, let's say, `my.css` and put it in CKEditor root folder.
Inside `my.css` type your attributes, for example:

```
p.ex1 
{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
p.ex2 
{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Now, in your `config.js` type this:

```
config.contentsCss = [CKEDITOR.getUrl('contents.css'), CKEDITOR.getUrl('my.css')];
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(ex1,ex2)';
```

This will load `my.css` in addition to the CKEditor's own `contents.css` and instruct CKEditor to allow `<p>` tags with `class` attributes named "ex1" and "ex2", so you can have `<p class="ex1">What are tokens?</p>`

More info:
[contentsCss](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) and [extraAllowedContent](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent)